# error in Index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When I run the rails server it returns with an error in index_html.erb. the code ran great for a few minutes then I came across this error.

[image: Index file]

routes.rb file

[[image: routes.rb[2]]

[[image: Index.html.erb file[3]]

Comment: Post your routes.rb file.

Comment: Its easier to read if you just cut and paste your routes into SO in a code block (indent 4 times for each row).  But if that is all that is uncommented in your routes.. then you don't have a home_about_path.  You'd need something like `get 'home/about', to: 'home#about', as: "home_about"`

Comment: You don't have `home_about_path` defined. You need to add a route for the about page. For example,  `get 'about' => 'home#about'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the `routes.rb` file to locate the various resources of your application, so any resource you expect your users to access will have to be defined in `routes.rb`. You don't have a route defined for `home_about_path`.

From your code, I take it you have an `about` method in your `home_controller.rb` controller file. You have to have the following line in your routes.rb (add it under '`get home#index`'):

```
get 'home#about' => 'home/about'
```

Adding this line should create a `home_about_path` and your `link_to` method should work.

Understanding routing is incredibly important to Rails development, so you should do some [reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and make sure you have a good grasp of the fundamentals before pushing too far ahead.